# Android JSON parsing using Retrofit and GSON gets malformed JSON error

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I am trying to make a weather app using the http://developer.forecast.io/ API. I am getting the error **`Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $`.** I've searched enough on this issue and got some answers but nothing worked on my app. Here are my codes:

**build.gradle: dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    //Retrofit
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    //POJO Annotation
    compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
}
```

**Pojo Model Class: Currently.java**

```
package com.github.abdalimran.weatherforecaster.pojoModels;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import javax.annotation.Generated;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Currently {

    @SerializedName("time")
    @Expose
    private int time;
    @SerializedName("summary")
    @Expose
    private String summary;
    @SerializedName("icon")
    @Expose
    private String icon;
    @SerializedName("precipIntensity")
    @Expose
    private double precipIntensity;
    @SerializedName("precipProbability")
    @Expose
    private double precipProbability;
    @SerializedName("precipType")
    @Expose
    private String precipType;
    @SerializedName("temperature")
    @Expose
    private double temperature;
    @SerializedName("apparentTemperature")
    @Expose
    private double apparentTemperature;
    @SerializedName("dewPoint")
    @Expose
    private double dewPoint;
    @SerializedName("humidity")
    @Expose
    private double humidity;
    @SerializedName("windSpeed")
    @Expose
    private double windSpeed;
    @SerializedName("windBearing")
    @Expose
    private int windBearing;
    @SerializedName("visibility")
    @Expose
    private double visibility;
    @SerializedName("cloudCover")
    @Expose
    private double cloudCover;
    @SerializedName("pressure")
    @Expose
    private double pressure;
    @SerializedName("ozone")
    @Expose
    private double ozone;

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The time
     */
    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param time
     *     The time
     */
    public void setTime(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The summary
     */
    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param summary
     *     The summary
     */
    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The icon
     */
    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param icon
     *     The icon
     */
    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The precipIntensity
     */
    public double getPrecipIntensity() {
        return precipIntensity;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param precipIntensity
     *     The precipIntensity
     */
    public void setPrecipIntensity(double precipIntensity) {
        this.precipIntensity = precipIntensity;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The precipProbability
     */
    public double getPrecipProbability() {
        return precipProbability;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param precipProbability
     *     The precipProbability
     */
    public void setPrecipProbability(double precipProbability) {
        this.precipProbability = precipProbability;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The precipType
     */
    public String getPrecipType() {
        return precipType;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param precipType
     *     The precipType
     */
    public void setPrecipType(String precipType) {
        this.precipType = precipType;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The temperature
     */
    public double getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param temperature
     *     The temperature
     */
    public void setTemperature(double temperature) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The apparentTemperature
     */
    public double getApparentTemperature() {
        return apparentTemperature;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param apparentTemperature
     *     The apparentTemperature
     */
    public void setApparentTemperature(double apparentTemperature) {
        this.apparentTemperature = apparentTemperature;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The dewPoint
     */
    public double getDewPoint() {
        return dewPoint;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param dewPoint
     *     The dewPoint
     */
    public void setDewPoint(double dewPoint) {
        this.dewPoint = dewPoint;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The humidity
     */
    public double getHumidity() {
        return humidity;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param humidity
     *     The humidity
     */
    public void setHumidity(double humidity) {
        this.humidity = humidity;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The windSpeed
     */
    public double getWindSpeed() {
        return windSpeed;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param windSpeed
     *     The windSpeed
     */
    public void setWindSpeed(double windSpeed) {
        this.windSpeed = windSpeed;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The windBearing
     */
    public int getWindBearing() {
        return windBearing;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param windBearing
     *     The windBearing
     */
    public void setWindBearing(int windBearing) {
        this.windBearing = windBearing;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The visibility
     */
    public double getVisibility() {
        return visibility;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param visibility
     *     The visibility
     */
    public void setVisibility(double visibility) {
        this.visibility = visibility;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The cloudCover
     */
    public double getCloudCover() {
        return cloudCover;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param cloudCover
     *     The cloudCover
     */
    public void setCloudCover(double cloudCover) {
        this.cloudCover = cloudCover;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The pressure
     */
    public double getPressure() {
        return pressure;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param pressure
     *     The pressure
     */
    public void setPressure(double pressure) {
        this.pressure = pressure;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The ozone
     */
    public double getOzone() {
        return ozone;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param ozone
     *     The ozone
     */
    public void setOzone(double ozone) {
        this.ozone = ozone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Weather Status: "+getSummary()+"\n"+
                "Precipitation: "+getPrecipType()+"\n"+
                "Pressure: "+getPressure()+"\n"+
                "Humidity: "+getHumidity()+"\n"+
                "Temperature: "+getTemperature();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.github.abdalimran.weatherforecaster;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.github.abdalimran.weatherforecaster.pojoModels.Currently;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        API_Interface weatherService = retrofit.create(API_Interface.class);
        Call<Currently> call = weatherService.getCurrentWeather(Constants.API_KEY,23.810514,90.3371889);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Currently>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Currently> call, Response<Currently> response) {
                textView.setText(response.body().toString());
                Log.d("result",response.body().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Currently> call, Throwable t) {
                textView.setText("Something went wrong: " + t.getMessage());
                Log.e("error",t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and the **JSON Response:**
Link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/22220252/

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here as far as I can tell is that the object you provide to retrofit doesn't match the json you provide in pastebin. They both need to match in a 1-to-1 basis. It does work for one of the fields in your json - `currently`, but the json is more than that.

So if you look at your java model, you have a model that works with:

```
 {
    "time": 1470336515,
    "summary": "Clear",
    "icon": "clear-night",
    "precipIntensity": 0.0021,
    "precipProbability": 0.05,
    "precipType": "rain",
    "temperature": 81.62,
    "apparentTemperature": 89.05,
    "dewPoint": 76.64,
    "humidity": 0.85,
    "windSpeed": 10.69,
    "windBearing": 138,
    "visibility": 2.49,
    "cloudCover": 0.22,
    "pressure": 999.91,
    "ozone": 269.33
}
```

which is the currently field inside the json you provide. If you want to serialize and deserialize the json you provided, you'll need to change the retrofit call to use another object that contains the `Currently` object inside. Something like this:

```
public class Prediction {
   @Expose
   @SerializedName("currently")
   private Currently currently;
   // ...
}
```

Then your retrofit call should look like:

```
    Call<Prediction> call = weatherService.getCurrentWeather(Constants.API_KEY,23.810514,90.3371889);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Prediction>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Prediction> call, Response<Prediction> response) {
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Prediction> call, Throwable t) {
            // ...
        }
    });
```

You'll obviously need to change the declaration of `getCurrentWeather`. Note also that I only did the `Prediction` model represent the field `currently`, but I think you can easily understand how to add the rest of the fields if you need them. Also `Prediction` was a name I've came up with, you can use whatever you'd like.